# Restrict "static" sub-domain aliases to non-HTML files, otherwise redirect to "www"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I've set up a couple of "domain aliases" for a website which I'm using as cookie-less sub-domains, so `static.domain.com/style.css` serves the same file as `www.domain.com/style.css`.

However, if someone tries to access `static.domain.com/index.htm` they should be 301 redirected to `www.domain.com/index.htm`. The `mod_rewrite` rules I have in the root web directory I thought would work but they don't seem to be.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # "/res/all.20110101.css" => "/res/all.css"
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$ $1.$3 [L]

    # Except for "static" sub-domains, force "www" when accessed without
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^s-img\.domain\.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^static\.domain\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    # If file requested is HTML, force "www" 
    <FilesMatch "\.(htm|html|php)$">
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com [NC]
        RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
    </FilesMatch>

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Just to clarify your rules: files like `/res/all.20110101.css` *don't* exist and the number is just for caching purposes, correct?

Comment: @nickgrim: Correct, that rule is for flexible filenames so cache-busting is more dependable than using query strings. http://j.mp/qs-cb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing around a bit with vbence's answer, I stumbled upon a more functional solution, although I'm not sure if it's the most optimised one.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On

   # Requests for "/res/all.20110101.css" serve up "/res/all.css", etc.
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.([0-9]+)\.([a-z]+)$ $1.$3 [L]

   # If the hostname isn't www.domain.com AND requested file's extension
   # isn't in the filter list, redirect to the www.domain.com version.
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(js|css|png|jpe?g|gif)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: I suggest adding a `$` after `!^www\.domain\.com`. For the very unlikely situation when you create a subdomain like `www.domain.com.someotherdomain.com`. It is just safer to be as specific as possible.

Answer (score 3):

This will redirect every request which does not go for static files:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It reads:

- IF hostname is not www.domain.com
- AND requested file does not end with an allowed extension
- Then redirect to the master (www) domain

Also for your versioning (you need the non-greedy `(.+?)` because `.+` would eat your whole string and there would be no match for the pattern):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.([0-9]+)\.([a-z]+)$ $1.$3 [L]
```

Comment: Added a separate rule for versioning.

Comment: Thanks vbence. I had trouble enabling a second static sub-domain using the first code chunk. I tried duplicating the first line and changing the sub-domain accordingly but it didn't work. Anyway, after messing around with it all, with a little help from you, I ended up with a more compact and functional mod_rewrite rule-set. I'll answer my own question with it as it more fully solved my question.

Comment: You did not say you needed a second domain. I saw it your code sample but dismissed it as you have not it mentioned in your question. Anyway, I would advise against using too compact rules. Chaninging them later is usually troublesome. Rather try to separate your rules to functional atomic units.

Comment: I have modified the first rule to redirect non-static content from all subdomains to your main site.

Comment: Maybe it wasn't clear but they were mentioned in the first sentence of the question.